# Find the number of roots lie in interval

Tags: derivatives

> Let $a \in R $ and let $f : R \rightarrow R $ be given by $f(x)=x^5 -5x + a $
>
> Then
>
> 1. $f(x)$ has three real roots if $a \gt 4$
> 2. $f(x)$ has only one real roots if $a \gt 4$
> 3. $f(x)$ has three real roots if $a \lt 4$
> 4. $f(x)$ has three real roots if $ -4 \lt  a \lt
>     4$

My work

If $$f(x)=0$$
$$ a=5x-x^5 =g(x)$$
$$g(x)=5x-x^5=0$$
$$x=0,5^{\frac{1}{4}},-5^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

I actually don't know how to do this type of question . Please tell me how to solve this type of question .

Comment: Sketch the function for different values of $a$ to develop your intuition. (label the stationary points as well, they should be easy to find, they are solutions to $x^4  = 1$).

Comment: I am not able to understand what your saying

Comment: Have you sketched the function for some value of $a$?

Comment: I added an answer, are you still confused?

Comment: @ZainPatel What is stationary point and how to conclude it ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reference minima and maxima instead, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the stationary points, their $x$-coordinates satisfy $x^4 =1 \iff x = \pm 1$ (since we are working over the reals. Now check $f(1) = a-4$ (minimum) and $f(-1) = a+4$ (maximum). Plotting the function for $a=0$ to develop our intuition of the problem is a good idea at this stage:

[image]

As can be see, the function will cross the $x$-axis at three distinct points as long as the maximum value of the function is greater than $0$, i.e: $a + 4 > 0 \iff a > -4$ and the minimum value of the functions is smaller than $0$, that is $a - 4 < 0 \iff a < 4$. So the required conditions on $a$ for there to be three roots are $$a \in (-4, 4)$$

I shall leave it to you to formalise the argument to your hearts content if you wish as well as investigate other cases for which intervals $a$ lies in, you can find restrictions on $a$ for there to be one root, two roots, no roots, etc...

Comment: How is this true? $x^5 -5x + 10$ has only one real root, at approximately x= -1.80219 .

Comment: @GovernmentFX Thank you! Minor oversight on my part (getting groggy...), should be fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Using the derivatives:
$$
y'=5x^4-5 \qquad y''=20x^3
$$
you can see that the functions has a local maximum for $x=-2$ with value $y(-1)=a+4$ and a minimum for $x=1$ with value $y(1)=a-4$

Now note that, since the function is a $5-$degree polynomial it has always at least a real root, and the limit of the function for $x\to -\infty$ is $-\infty$ and the limit of the function for $x\to +\infty$ is $+\infty$

So, if $y(-1)$ and $y(1)$ have the same sign, there is no roots between $-1$ and $1$ and the function is alway negative before the unique root and positive after it.

If $y(-1)$ and $y(1)$ have opposite signs, than there is a root between them and other two roots, one before $-1$ and the other after $1$.

Finally you have the possibility that $y(-1)=0$ or $y(1)=0$, and , in this case, the function has a simple root and a double root.

Answer (score 1):

The roots are such that

$$x^5-5x=-a$$

which means that they are the intersection of the curve $y=x^5-5x$ with the horizontal $y=-a$.

By a study of the curve (extrema), you can establish the following table of variations

$$\begin{matrix}x&-\infty&&-1&&+1&&+\infty\\x^5-5x&-\infty&\nearrow&+4&\searrow&-4&\nearrow&+\infty\end{matrix}$$

This tells you that for $-a<-4$ or $-a>+4$ (below or above the two extrema), there is a single root, and there are three in between.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering the derivative $f'(x)=5(x^2-1)$, you see $f$ a a local maximum M=f(-1) first, then a local minimum $m=f(1)$.  Thus,

- $f(x)$ has one real root if $m$ and $M$ have the same sign, i.e. if and only if 
  $$mM=f(1)f(-1)=(a-4)(a+4)>0\iff\begin{cases}a>4 \enspace\text{or}\enspace a<-4\end{cases},$$
- $f(x)$ has three roots if $m$ and $M$ have different signs, i.e. if and only if $-4<a<4$,
- $f(x)$ has one multiple root and one simple root if $a=\pm4$.  One checks the multiple root ($1$ or $-1$) is a double root.

Comment: How you concluded there will be three roots and one multiple root ?

Comment: Maximum and minimum have different  signs. Considering the sign of the derivative, the function is increasing first (starting from $-\infty$) so the maximum is positive, the negative minimum comes next, then the function tends to $+\infty$. $$$$ For the multiple root, $1$ or $-1$ is one of the roots (depending on the value of $a$), and it is an extremum.